# Are multiple aws snapshots cost effective?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm currently taking a daily snapshot of every volume on every single instances I have. This causes me to have quite a lot of snapshots / week.

I'm now wondering the following:

- is it more cost-effective if I delete some of these snapshots?
- is there any danger whatsoever when I delete a snapshot(except for the snapshot-only-data)?

Comment: impossible to say if it is "cost effective".  What is the consequence of not having the snapshots?  Voting to close as "unclear what you are asking"

Comment: @Vinoth please don't use `inline code` to highlight random terms.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, will take care next time.

Comment: @Vorsprung: I'm not asking if it is cost effective to have snapshots. I'm asking if it is cost-effective to have multiple small snapshots compared to 1 big snapshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to be able to roll back to one of the exact points in time that the snapshot represents then it is "cost-effective".   If not you do not need many many snapshots.

Quote from official docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-creating-snapshot.html

> If you make periodic snapshots of a volume, the snapshots are incremental so that only the blocks on the device that have changed after your last snapshot are saved in the new snapshot. Even though snapshots are saved incrementally, the snapshot deletion process is designed so that you need to retain only the most recent snapshot in order to restore the volume.

So, let's assume you take a snapshot on Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday

To restore on Thursday to the point in time for the Wednesday snapshot only requires the Wednesday snapshot.  If this is your requirement then the Monday and Tuesday snapshots can be removed.  If they are removed then the costs they would accrue will not be there and that could be a cost saving.

What the cost saving is will depend on the size of the volumes and the rate of change, from the docs (  https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/ )

> Snapshot storage is based on the amount of space your data consumes in Amazon S3. Because data is compressed before being saved to Amazon S3, and Amazon EBS does not save empty blocks, it is likely that the snapshot size will be considerably less than your volume size. For the first snapshot of a volume, Amazon EBS saves a full copy of your data to Amazon S3. For each incremental snapshot, only the changed part of your Amazon EBS volume is saved.

If you need to be able to restore to the point in time of the Tuesday snapshot then you must keep that one as well.  If you need to get back to Monday you need to keep the Monday one

How many snapshots you keep depends on what type of recovery you need